# custom post types containing a collection of items

Tags: custom-post-types, database

i have a custom post type products.How can i add a collection of items to that custom post type like this:

**Product A**
title
description
price
option1
option2
option3
option n

Option items can be 0-n
In a relational database it would be like this:
table_products (product_id, title,...)
table_options (**product_id**, option_id,...)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've got the Custom Post Type a bit wrong, the products are not saved in products table but in the posts table

```
prefix_posts(post_id,title,content,...
```

So to use the options in relation to post_id you can use the build-in [**custom fields**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields)
which are key/value pairs.

> The key is the name of the meta-data
>   element. The value is the information
>   that will appear in the meta-data list
>   on each individual post that the
>   information is associated with.

either by using the build-in UI or creating a custom metabox [**by plugin**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/verve-meta-boxes/) or [**by code**](http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/2010/05/howto-meta-box-wordpress.html)
and they are saved in postmeta table

```
prefix_postmeta(meta_id,post_id,meta_key,meta_value)
```

and to access these option you use [get_post_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) function:

```
$meta_values = get_post_meta($post_id, $key, $single);
```

for example say you have a field named price so to get its value:

```
$price = get_post_meta($post_id, 'price', true);
```

and this will get the price of the product with the same post_id.

hope this helps.

Comment: i've used both custom post types and custom fields, but i need something different.

The "options" aren't key/value pairs.

A better example:


Custom post type "houses" and custom post type "rooms", how can i associate the rooms with the houses?

Comment: That depends on your needs, you can associate  houses with rooms by storring the room  post type ID's in a house post type custom field, you can associate by custom taxonomy, you can set room post type as a child post of house post type or you can use `post2post` plugin that creates a many to many relation between posts, but i think that's a different question and again mostly depends on you needs